# How to split an array without 0 in the output in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

Here's my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.*;

public class lalala {
    public static Scanner input;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input array: ");
        String n = input.nextLine();
        String[] x= n.split("");

        int[] array = new int [x.length];
        for(int i=1;i<x.length;i++){ //this is the loop i want to ask
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(x[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));     

    }
}
```

And this is my input & output:

```
Input array: 1234
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How can I print the output without 0?

And one more question, why I can't start the (for)loop from 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you split your input `1234`, what you get is `[, 1, 2, 3, 4]` - an array of size `5`.

Due to this, your `int[] array` becomes of length `5` and all the `5` elements are initialized to `0`.

Then you update the elements from `1st` index to `4th` index by the numbers `1,2,3,4` which keeps the `0th` index as it is.

Thats why you are getting `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` as an output.

Try this :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lalala {

    public static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input array: ");
        String n = input.nextLine();            //1234
        String[] x = n.split("");               //[,1,2,3,4]
        int[] array = new int[x.length - 1];    // size = 4
        for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            array[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(x[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Another approach for what you want using [`String#toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lalala {

    public static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input array: ");
        String n = input.nextLine();
        char[] x = n.toCharArray();
        int[] array = new int[x.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { //this is the loop i want to ask
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(x[i] + "");
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation and the code it's work ^_^b
by the way the second question, i still don't get it??

Comment: by the way can you tell me why i can start the loop from 0 with split string?

Comment: Assuming you meant "why i can't" in the above comment, after you split the string `1234`, the element at index `0` is an `empty string` which you don't want. What you want is the element at index `1`.

Comment: ah.. ok i got it, thanks a lot bro.. And sorry for the my typo :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if this is part of a study of the Java language, then I suggest you adopt the conventions and make the class name capitalized.

Second - it seems to me your input is `1 2 3 4` and not as specified, otherwise the int array would contain one value of `1234`

Third - what are you asking exactly? if you ask why the first cell in the array is zero, then I answer it's becuase arrays in Java start with index 0 (like all C-family) and arrays of type int get initilzed to value 0 by the compiler. The cell at index 0 is never assigned any value in the loop, which starts at 1

if you ask how to skip the value of 0 in the print, then you will have to replace the convinience of the `Arrays` utility with an explicit loop

Comment: actually i want to ask about how to skip the zero, and i know that an array start from 0, then another problem show up and it's make me be anxious to find out why i can't start the loop from 0? It's give me an error when i use "for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)" so i use "int=1"

Comment: yep int=1 it's work but when i change it to 0 it give me an error like this:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at lalala.main(lalala.java:17)
"
that's why i am asking you :3
sorry i am still beginner

Answer (score 0):

It's because the index of an array starts at 0, not at one, so change your for loop to

```
for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){ //start from i=0
```

Comment: i know a loop start from 0, but when i start it from 0 it's give me an error.  that's why my another question is " why i can't start the loop from 0?"

Answer (score 0):

Because the index of an array starts with 0,not at 1.
Just change the loop,

```
for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
//Your code enter here
}
```

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. The OP asks why he can't start the loop with 0.